# How can I create a JSONPath filter expression containing both AND and OR operators?

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net, jsonpath

I have a requirement where i am trying to select objects inside a JSON string by filtering on the presence and/or values of multiple properties of objects inside a JSON array.

Here is an example of my JSON:

```
{'Fields':[{
  "Sub_Status": "Pending",
  "Status": "Pending",
  "Patient_Gender": "M"
}]}
```

I want to check this json string using query like this (below query is a SQL query)

```
string query = TRIM(UPPER(Status)) IN ('PENDING', 'DISPENSED','SHIPMENT') AND TRIM(Patient_Gender) IS NOT NULL

string json_string = {'Fields':[{
  "Sub_Status": "Pending",
  "Status": "Pending",
  "Patient_Gender": "M"
}]};

var test = json_string.Where(query).toString() /// a return of bool = true or false
```

I tried using JSONPath and also system.linq.dynamic, But no luck.

**UPDATE**

I need the response in c#. As of now. I tried to use the NewtonSoft.Json SelectToken to select a token using a JSONPath query.

The first part of my query as of now is:

```
JToken test = s.SelectToken("$.Fields[?(@.Status == 'Pending' || @.Status == 'PENDING' || @.Status == 'SHIPMENT' || @.Status == 'DISPENSED')]");
```

The second part of my query is:

```
JToken test = s.SelectToken("$.Fields[?(@.Patient_Gender != '')]");
```

The problem is with "and" operator -- I do not know how to combine them in a single JSONPath query. Individually the queries are working. I need the syntax for the "and" operator. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: 1. I looking for solution mainly in c#.2. Tried these with json path $[?(@.Status == 'SHIPMENT'),?(@.Status == 'PENDING'),?(@.Status == 'Pending'),?(@.Status == 'DISPENSED')] or $[?(@.Patient_Gender == '')]. But the problem is that i was not able to do and operator. also i was not able to do not null. I want some one to send the condition like the on above and i want to parse my json string if the condition is matched or not.

Comment: I am using NewtonSoft.json and trying to add the jsonpath using SelectToken and adding the json path. Problems are with and operator and also the not null. Sorry if my question is not concise. I am still learning.

Comment: I was able to solve the not Null  by adding the query as $[?(@.Patient_Gender != '')]. Now the only problem is with and operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Newtonsoft's JSONPath implementation does support an `AND` operator, as can be seen in the [source for QueryExpression.cs](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JsonPath/QueryExpression.cs#L19)
.  It uses the `&&` syntax.  Thus if you want to search for fields that have `Status == 'Pending'` and have a `Patient_Gender` property present (with any value), you would do:

```
var query = s.SelectTokens("$.Fields[?(@.Status == 'Pending' && @.Patient_Gender)]");
```

However, you are *mixing* `&&` and `||` operators, and unfortunately the order of precedence of these two operators is undocumented.  The [JSONPath website](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) says, uselessly, that `()` is a **script expression, using the underlying script engine.**  And the [Newtonsoft documentation](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) says nothing at all beyond referring the reader to that same JSONPath website!

You might want to [open a documentation issue with Newtonsoft](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues) asking them to clarify the precedence of the `||` and `&&` operators in JSONPath.

Thus to get your desired query, you have the following options:

1. I have found from experiment that `&&` and `||` associate left-to-right with equal precedence.  Thus `A && B || C` means `A && (B || C)` while `A || B && C` means `A || (B && C)`

   You apparently want the former.  *As long as you are willing to depend on undocumented behavior*, the following query should work:

   ```
   var filter = "$.Fields[?(@.Patient_Gender && @.Status == 'Pending' || @.Status == 'PENDING' || @.Status == 'SHIPMENT' || @.Status == 'DISPENSED')]";
   var query = s.SelectTokens(filter);
   var result = query.ToList();
   ```
2. You can use [`Enumerable.Intersect()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) to combine query results:

   ```
   var query1 = s.SelectTokens("$.Fields[?(@.Status == 'Pending' || @.Status == 'PENDING' || @.Status == 'SHIPMENT' || @.Status == 'DISPENSED')]");
   var query2 = s.SelectTokens("$.Fields[?(@.Patient_Gender)]");
   var query = query1.Intersect(query2);

   var result = query.ToList();
   ```
3. You can use a [`Enumerable.Where()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418.aspx) to do the filtering and just use `SelectTokens()` to do the enumeration:

   ```
   var query = from t in s.SelectTokens("$.Fields[*]")
               where (string)t["Patient_Gender"] != null
               let status = (string)t["Status"]
               where status == "Pending" || status == "PENDING" || status == "SHIPMENT" || status == "DISPENSED"
               select t;

   var result = query.ToList();
   ```

If you just want to know if anything matches, rather than a list of tokens that match, you can use [`Any()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337697.aspx), e.g.

```
var result = query.Any();
```

Incidentally, the following attempts *did not work*:

4. Trying to parenthesize the logical operators throws a `JsonException: Unexpected character while parsing path query: (`:

   ```
   var filter = "$.Fields[?((@.Status == 'Pending' || @.Status == 'PENDING' || @.Status == 'SHIPMENT' || @.Status == 'DISPENSED') && (@.Patient_Gender))]";
   var query = s.SelectTokens(filter);
   var result = query.ToList();
   ```
5. Puttting `&&` after `||` incorrectly selected tokens that matched one of the `||` clauses but not the `&&` clause:

   ```
   var filter = "$.Fields[?(@.Status == 'Pending' || @.Status == 'PENDING' || @.Status == 'SHIPMENT' || @.Status == 'DISPENSED' && @.Patient_Gender)]";
   var query = s.SelectTokens(filter);
   var result = query.ToList();
   ```

Here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hhvold) showing the both the working and non-working queries.

Comment: Thanks dbc. I tried the combinations and also i tried the precedence based operator use. I liked the Intersect response. thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you need to Deserialize your json into object or objects (in case of multiple records) and test that object(s).

Go to your Solution Explorer > Right Click => Manage Nuget Packages => Download Netwonsoft.Json, Then create a class with similar json structure :

```
public class Case
{
    public string Sub_Status { set; get; }
    public string Status { set; get; }
    public string Patient_Gender { set; get; }
}
```

Then in your Program:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string json_string = @"{""Sub_Status"": ""Pending"",
                            ""Status"": ""Pending"",
                            ""Patient_Gender"": ""M""}";

    Case caseObj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Case>(json_string);

    List<string> acceptedStatuses = new List<string> { "PENDING", "DISPENSED", "SHIPMENT" };

    bool test = statuses.Any(s => s.Equals(caseObj.Status, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                            && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(caseObj.Patient_Gender);
}
```