# Does the Json.NET JsonPath implementation support nested conditional expressions?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

A single-level conditional expression is valid like:

`$[?(@['PropA'] == 'V1' && @['PropB'] == 'V2')]`

But, if I build a JsonPath expression like:

`$[?((@['PropA'] == 'V1' && @['PropB'] == 'V2') || (@['PropA'] == 'V3' && @['PropB'] == 'V4'))]`

Is this a valid JSON Path that can be parsed by Newtonsoft Json.NET?

Comment: Last time I checked Json.NET did not support grouping of expressions in JSONPath logical expressions.  See: [How can I create a JSONPath filter expression containing both AND and OR operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38233178/3744182).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is a thorough explanation of why the answer is "no" as well as some suggested workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38256828/2092250